# Invalid redirect URI on spotify auth

Tags: authentication, spotify

I try to auth user through my app with spotify Web API but 
I receive this error:

```
INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI
```

URL:

```
GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=6ae90bf75bf748c8874a75d16682f0c5&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email
```

I cant see where is the problem... Can you help?

Answer (score 120):

You have to add the redirect URI to the White-list in ["My Applications" panel](https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications/).

e.g http://example.com/callback/

Comment: Ok, i added the url in the white list but i get the same error.

Comment: I forgot to add slash after redirect_uri. Redirect url need to be eq with the url from the white list. Thank you for help mallendeo.

Comment: and then what? I am running a CLIENT not a server.

Comment: Spotify App Panel > Edit Settings > Add URL

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, try to reset the navigator cache. It worked for me (I just changed to Chrome Incognito).

Answer (score 33):

app.js:

```
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback';
```

(https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard) Spotify > My application:

```
http://localhost:8888/callback
```

Dont forget to save.

Comment: This answer is still relevant in 2020 and solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue when authenticated via Authorization Code Flow.

Per the docs `The value of this parameter must exactly match the value of redirect_uri supplied when requesting the authorization code.`
So make sure that the:

1. `redirect_uri` that is configured in the dashboard
2. `redirect_uri` in the GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
3. `redirect_uri` in the POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

is exactly the same or else you will get a INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI

Comment: Ok, but when I click Google login I get back a google auth link and same error appears. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Navigate to your Spotify developer dashboard and open the project you are working on.

Next click "edit settings" and look for the redirect URIs field.

Put your redirect URI in the field. ex: `http://localhost:8888/callback`

Click save.

You should be good

Answer (score 2):

First. You have to be sure that you're using **app.js** from **authorization_code** directory.

Second. Be sure you edited app.js. That third line is important.

```js
var client_id = '---'; // Your client id
var client_secret = '---'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'; // Your redirect uri - EXAMPLE
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the SpotifyAPI-NET API wrapper by JohnnyCrazy and was having this problem despite adding the URL I specified in my wrapper call to my white list as specified above.

The browser's address bar should show the redirect URL it is using buried in the middle of the string - I found that it was also making a request with "https://accounts.spotify.com:8000/authorize" as the redirect URL - perhaps the wrapper is making 2 API calls, but I found that only by whitelisting *both* this URL and the one I was specifying would it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is super specific, so make sure you have exact url in each place.

In my app dashboard on spotify I had:
http://localhost:3005/

And my url is:
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http
%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:3005/&scope=user-read-currently-playing%20user-top-read

Note the trailing slash in both places.

Comment: Thank you for this. Using the url you used worked for me. Using 8888 did not work, as I was calling this from a Jupyter notebook (didn't realize beforehand)!

Answer (score 1):

This error also appears when the redirect_uri is missing in the request. I figured that out the hard way due to writing "redirect_url" (with an L) instead.

Took me way too long to figure out. Hopefully this can save someone else some time.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to adding 'http://localhost:8888/callback' to the Redirect URIs list in your App's settings via https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications

It's a shame this is not mentioned on the quick start:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/

Answer (score 0):

> Include a path after the first pair of forward slashes. For example:
>   Your app name is My Awesome App The redirect URI may be
>   my-awesome-app-login://callback or
>   awesomeprotocol123://returnafterlogin.
>
> For more information please refer this link
>   [Spotify Redirect URI Example](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/)