# Spotify API: Invalid redirect URI

Tags: spotify

I am fairly new to web development, and I have been trying to make a web app with Python using the Spotify API.

I've tried to experiment with getting authorization to a user's account and I've tried entering this into my browser (replacing "CLIENTID" with my client id): https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=CLIENTID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback

However, I'm getting the error:

> INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI.

I have white listed http://example.com/callback in my account, so that shouldn't be a problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi welcome to the SO community. If you whitelisted "http://example.com/callback" that does not work, use this instead: http://localhost:8888/callback

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956443/invalid-redirect-uri-on-spotify-auth/56158832#56158832), essentially the redirect URI should be exactly the same as the one that is whitelisted on the spotify dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For who are getting this error, try to use this redirect URI in the Spotify's dashboard:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/spotify
```