# Spotipy: Trying to get top artist based on Spotify username

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to get the top artists from a Spotify username (That is not my own) however I am getting `INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI` page when doing so. What would be the right steps to implement this idea?

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import spotipy.util as util

#Set up the Spotify API client
SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = "X"
SPOTIFY_SECRET = "X"
SCOPE = "user-top-read"
REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8888/callback/"
USERNAME = "X"

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(USERNAME,scope=SCOPE,client_id=SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,client_secret=SPOTIFY_SECRET, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    # Get user's top artists for spotify wrapped
    top_artists = sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=50, time_range="medium_term")
else:
    print("Can't get token for", USERNAME)

#Print the user's top artists
print("Your top artists from the past 6 months are:")
for artist in top_artists["items"]:
    print(artist["name"])
```

I have tried to log out of Spotify and log back in but it doesn't work in order to try and clear the cache. I have also included my redirect_uri into the Spotify dashboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid redirect URI on spotify auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956443/invalid-redirect-uri-on-spotify-auth)

Comment: This answers one of my questions. I am able to get the artists however it is linked to my own personal account. I want the top artists of another users @TrooperZ

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the callback URL in the settings for your app on the [Developer Dashboard](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard).

Simply log in, find your app and click "Edit Settings" in the top right section. Under redirect URIs you ad http://localhost:8888/callback and remember to click save in the bottom. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello thanks for the comment! I did do this however I am still unable to access the data of a specific user. It only gives me data for my own Spotify account

Comment: When you add Redirect URIs, you will click on "Add" button first and then on "Save" button ? And you still see "INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI" on page?

Comment: I think there is no way to get top artists from another account. If you check top_artists['href'] you'll see that request send to 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists?limit=50&offset=0' URL, which means you need to log in to this account first.